# Most effective way to redirect a huge amount of URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

What is the most effective way to redirect a huge amount of URLs?

I'm working on a website with hundreds (potentially more than 1,000+ but I have not fully checked) urls that need redirecting. What would be the most effective way of doing this? Not all of the URLs follow the same structure.

I could just put each individual URL redirect in the .htaccess but would that be a very efficient way of doing it?

Some example urls -

```
http://website.com/category/category/1238/productname
http://website.com/pagename
http://website.com/1239/productname
http://website.com/date/page
```

The pages need to be redirected to another relevant page. For example /product/pagename/category/232323 needs to be redirected to /product/232323 (just an example. I won't actually be using this structure)

Comment: Where do you want to redirect these links to? What have you tried so far?

Comment: probably there's a scheme or pattern which can be used in order to generate the new URL from the old one. If so, you may do it via php which then is more generic.

Comment: The pages need to be redirected to another relevant page. For example /product/pagename/category/232323 needs to be redirected to /product/232323 (just an example. I won't actually be using this structure)